# Docker exits container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build my own docker image for apache2 and PHP. Can anyone tell my why my container exits after run when it supposes to run ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]?

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y nano vim iputils-ping sudo git curl php php-cli php-fpm
RUN apt install -y php-json php-mysql
RUN apt install -y php-zip php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath
RUN apt install psmisc -y

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOF_DIR /var/log/apache2

# RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash devwl

EXPOSE 80/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Build command:

```
docker build -t www .
```

Run command:

```
docker run -itd -p 80:80 www
```

Ouput docker ps:
[image]

Comment: run it without `-d` and see the logs

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to build your Dockerfile. `docker logs` shows a problem with start command. Running container without `-D` option works well...

`CMD ["apache2ctl", "start"]`

Do you need to use <IfDefine ...> in conf files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the `ENTRYPOINT` line.

Since you have both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, they [get combined together into a single argument list](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  That means you have an effective command like

```bash
ENTRYPOINT+CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

But `sh -c` only reads in the single next argument and executes it.  The remaining arguments would be accessible inside that string as positional parameters `$0`, `$1`, ... but unless you refer to one of those then the command you're eventually running is only `apachectl` with no arguments.

You only need to invoke a shell at all if your command uses shell features (referencing environment variables or running multiple commands).  Yours doesn't, so you don't need anything that mentions a shell; just delete the `ENTRYPOINT` and have the existing `CMD` start Apache.

In a Dockerfile, you shouldn't usually need to say `sh -c` at all.  If you do need to invoke a shell to run some command, you can use [Docker shell syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) as a plain string without the JSON-array syntax; for example

```bash
# needs a shell because of $VARIABLE and command; command syntax
CMD touch "$APACHE_LOG_DIR/started"; exec apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
```

(If you do need to override this command with `docker run` arguments or in a Compose `command:`, these syntaxes will not automatically insert a shell wrapper and there you do need to specifically say `sh -c 'some command'` if you need a shell to process the command string; again note the single quotes to make the command string a single argument.)